# Curl within while loop only sending variables once but runs the loop multiple times

Tags: php, loops, curl, while-loop

The code below is only sending one variable to my script but it is running trough the loop as normal. I would appreciate some help with this. Thank You.

```
<?php    
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id =$id");         
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

        //$user_phone = $row['phone'];
        $phone = $row['email'];
        $email = $row['phone'];

        $url = 'http://example.com/request.php?phone='.$phone.'&email='.$email.'';
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => '5'
        ));
        $resp = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think try to seperate curl statement from the loop.

```
<?php    
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id =$id");         
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

  //$user_phone = $row['phone'];
  $phone = $row['email'];
  $email = $row['phone'];
  $url = 'http://example.com/request.php?phone='.$phone.'&email='.$email.'';
  call_curl($url);
  }
 ?>

    function call_curl($url){
     $curl = curl_init();
     curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
     CURLOPT_URL => $url,
     CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => '5'
     ));
     $resp = curl_exec($curl);
     curl_close($curl);
    }
```